# Pass drag event from div to mapbox layer

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jes4fggd/.
I want to move the map, but as the div follows the mouse pointer looks like the event is catched by div. I want to pass this event to map when the mouse is over the div or buttons. I want only click event is available for buttons but drag is for map. 
I tried to use voteDiv1.style['pointer-events'] = 'none'; but it is kind of tricky for me. Is there any simple way?
Thanks.

```
var voteDiv1 = document.getElementById('vote1');
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var c = map.project(e.lngLat);
    console.log(c)
    voteDiv1.style.left = (c.x) -50 + 'px';
    voteDiv1.style.top = (c.y) -50 + 'px';
});
```

and another example https://jsfiddle.net/q3ghvuu3/ - how to move a map or click a button in this way?

Comment: `pointer-events: none` makes the div move smoothly, but then you can't click on the voting buttons. What kind of interaction are you going for?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I need to process any click events inside/over red bordered div and be able to drag the map when the mouse pointer is over that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confused about what you're going for based on the description but here's my best guess:

- Clicking the map should drag the map as expected
- Clicking the button should click the button as expected
- Moving the cursor around the map should move the button around the map
- Clicking and dragging the button should drag the map (not expected by most users)

I'll reiterate my initial concerns that this UI is a bad idea. Users are familiar with seeing buttons overlaid on maps, like zoom buttons on Google Maps, and know that to drag the map they click anywhere *but* the buttons. So I'd still recommend against doing this. But here it is.

To accomplish it, we'll add `pointer-events: none` to the button element. That way all clicks and drags go through to the map. We then check the location of the click to see if it happened in the same location as the button, and if so dispatch a `click` event to the button.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmVuZGVybGlvIiwiYSI6ImNqM29qdXR5djAwMTQzM214M2hnZWVycWsifQ.jtDIyytOGMJ0TS9Pp6zFVg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
  center: [-74.50, 40],
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});

var voteDiv1 = document.getElementById('vote1');
map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var c = map.project(e.lngLat);
  voteDiv1.style.left = (c.x) - 50 + 'px';
  voteDiv1.style.top = (c.y) - 50 + 'px';
});

document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Plus clicked")
})

document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var button = document.getElementById("plus");
  var buttonBB = button.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (
    event.pageX > buttonBB.left &&
    event.pageX < buttonBB.right &&
    event.pageY > buttonBB.top &&
    event.pageY < buttonBB.bottom
  ) {
    var bottomEvent = new Event("click");
    bottomEvent.pageX = event.pageX;
    bottomEvent.pageY = event.pageY;

    button.dispatchEvent(bottomEvent);
  }
  
  
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#vote1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>

<div id="vote1">
  <div id="box" sectionId="" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <button id="plus" style="width:150px; height:150px">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what if I have one big button that follows a mouse, and I want to click it or drag a map. like this https://jsfiddle.net/q3ghvuu3/

Comment: If that JSFiddle does what you want can't you use that code?

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to click and hold on the button, and have it drag the map? I would recommend against that on the basis of bad UI.

Comment: Yes. I want to click the button or maybe just a div will be better and be able to drag a map. 2 separate events - click it - something happend and the other one is drag a map. I can't drag a map as the div intercepts the drag event. The problem is to pass a drag event. Thanks

Comment: How are the 2 solutions above different from what you want?

Comment: I think I understand what you want. I'll post a solution shortly. However, I still think it's a poor UI and would recommend against it.

Comment: @SERG - solution is updated based on your feedback. And I'll take this chance to say again, I think the UI is really poor - dragging the underlying map by clicking a button is not expected.